# Insert value from one dataframe to another without using list?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `dictionary` in the following format

```
cust_dict = {ABC:['Particulars','Date'], BCD:['Particulars','Date']}
```

The `'Particulars'` and `'Date'` are columns of the `DataFrame` i.e. `ABC` and `BCD`

There is a separate `DataFrame` `df` from which I want to insert value into the columns, I tried

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
     cust_name = row['Particulars']
     cust_dict[cust_name]['Particulars'] = row['Particulars']
     cust_dict[cust_name]['Date'] = row['Date']
```

It just doesn't work.

I have tried `assign`, `at`, etc.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What is your expected out put ?

Comment: To get quick help you should show us how the dataframes look like (share a smaller sample) and your expected output. You are leaving us in the dark.

Comment: sorry about that. I just got back from office and this problem has been nagging me. Don't have access to the the files to generate the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Your dictionary contains a list each. So, you'd solve your problem by:

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
     cust_name = row[0]
     cust_dict[cust_name][0] = row[0]
     cust_dict[cust_name][1] = row[1]
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: Hi, I think I may have screwed up the presentation of the dictionary. Each key has a dataframe with the `Particulars` etc as column headers. Right now each key of the dictionary has an empty dataframe.